# How to reduce to find lowest date for each year from section of dates

Tags: javascript, typescript

Right now I have a for-loop going over the dates. I first sort the order and then pluck the first date of each year, but I feel like this could be used with `.reduce()` instead and converting the results with `Object.values(result)` would return me the array or 3 dates.

Reducing with one tenerary would get me the lowest overall date. But I am stuck where I need to return the lowest date from each year within the section.

```
.reduce((a,b) =>
a = moment(a) < moment(a) ? a : b
return a
)
```

If there are better ways to achive the end result I am all ears.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  firstDatesOfYear = [];

  data = [
    '2022-02-14T00:00:00',
    '2021-06-14T00:00:00',
    '2021-06-21T00:00:00',
    '2021-11-01T00:00:00',
    '2022-01-10T00:00:00',
    '2022-01-03T00:00:00',
    '2020-07-20T00:00:00',
    '2020-08-31T00:00:00',
    '2020-09-07T00:00:00',
    '2021-02-22T00:00:00',
    '2021-06-07T00:00:00',
    '2022-01-17T00:00:00',
    '2022-01-24T00:00:00',
    '2022-01-31T00:00:00',
  ];

  // find first date of each year from non sorted list of ISO dates
  // result should be ["2020-07-20T00:00:00", "2021-02-22T00:00:00", "2022-01-03T00:00:00"]

  constructor() {
    let temp = this.data
      .map((day) => moment(day))
      .sort((a, b) => a.unix() - b.unix());
    // stuck here, instead of doing the whole following below - should use .reduce()?

    console.log(temp);

    for (let i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
      if (i == 0) {
        this.firstDatesOfYear.push(temp[i]);
      } else if (moment(temp[i]).year() != moment(temp[i + 1]).year()) {
        this.firstDatesOfYear.push(temp[i + 1]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Problem: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-moment-example-z7m92c?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Edit. I ended up using something like this.

```js
.reduce((datesMap, curr) => {
  const date = new Date(curr),
        year = date.getFullYear();

  if (datesMap.has(year)) {
    if (date.getTime() < datesMap.get(year).getTime())
      datesMap.set(year, date);
  } else {
    datesMap.set(year, date);
  }
  
  return datesMap;
}, new Map());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't pretend to know everything that's going on, but an easy way to find the first date is with `.sort()`.

```js
const data = [
  "2022-02-14T00:00:00",
  "2021-06-14T00:00:00",
  "2021-06-21T00:00:00",
  "2021-11-01T00:00:00",
  "2022-01-10T00:00:00",
  "2022-01-03T00:00:00",
  "2020-07-20T00:00:00",
  "2020-08-31T00:00:00",
  "2020-09-07T00:00:00",
  "2021-02-22T00:00:00",
  "2021-06-07T00:00:00",
  "2022-01-17T00:00:00",
  "2022-01-24T00:00:00",
  "2022-01-31T00:00:00",
];

const firstDatePerYear = data
  .sort((a, b) => new Date(a) - new Date(b))
  .reduce((acc, curr) => {
    const year = new Date(curr).getFullYear();
    if (!acc[year]) acc[year] = curr;
    return acc;
  }, {});

console.log(firstDatePerYear);

/*
{
  '2020': '2020-07-20T00:00:00',
  '2021': '2021-02-22T00:00:00',
  '2022': '2022-01-03T00:00:00'
}
*/
```

Comment: Dates are already sorted with `.sort((a, b) => a.unix() - b.unix());`, I am looking for ways to reduce the sorted days to find lowest date from each year. Thanks for trying.

Comment: After sorting, you can use reduce to make an object with the lowest date from every year. Get the `.getFullYear` then add it to the accumulator. Once you add that year to the accumulator, you ignore anything else that is in that specific year.

Comment: Just pointing out that your function should be wrapped with `Object.values` to get array of date strings and Date obj's should use numeric value e.g `new Date(a).valueOf() - new Date(b).valueOf()`. Otherwise good job!

Comment: True, you can use .valueOf if you're unfamiliar with how JS automatic type conversion works or want to be more explicit.

Answer (score 1):

The idea to use `.reduce()` is one possible way to achieve the objective. Combine it with `Object.values()` and below is one possible implementation:

```js
const origData = [
    '2022-02-14T00:00:00',
    '2021-06-14T00:00:00',
    '2021-06-21T00:00:00',
    '2021-11-01T00:00:00',
    '2022-01-10T00:00:00',
    '2022-01-03T00:00:00',
    '2020-07-20T00:00:00',
    '2020-08-31T00:00:00',
    '2020-09-07T00:00:00',
    '2021-02-22T00:00:00',
    '2021-06-07T00:00:00',
    '2022-01-17T00:00:00',
    '2022-01-24T00:00:00',
    '2022-01-31T00:00:00',
  ];
  
  const getFirstDates = (arr = origData) => (
    Object.values(
      arr.reduce(
        (fin, itm) => ({
          ...fin,
          [moment(itm).format('YYYY')]: (
            fin[moment(itm).format('YYYY')] &&
            fin[moment(itm).format('YYYY')] < itm
              ? fin[moment(itm).format('YYYY')]
              : itm
          )
        }),
        {}
      )
    )
  );
  
  console.log(getFirstDates());
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/moment@2.29.1/moment.js"></script>
```

**Explanation**

- Use `.reduce()` to obtain an `object` with props as the `year` and values as the earliest date of that year
- Use `Object.values()` to extract just the values (which will be earliest date on each given year)

**How reduce works**

- `fin` is the aggregator & is initially set to `{}` (empty object)
- `itm` is the iterator (ie, each date in the `origData` array)
- If the `year` of the current `itm` already exists, then check if the existing value in the aggregator `fin[moment(itm).format('YYYY')]` is lesser than `itm` (ie, whether the date is earlier than the one in `itm`)
- If the existing date is earlier, do nothing (ie, return it as-is)
- Otherwise, repopulate the value with `itm`

Comment: Doesn't look any prettier than mine but given that we have reduced I will accept this answer.